# How to separate the dto mapping logic

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, design-patterns, architecture, mapping

I'm facing some problems to organize my mapping methods in my code. I'm doing the mapping logic in the controller layer but some entities needs diferents dtos to each operation (insert, update e delete).

I created a generic controller with 2 types: the original entity and the dto type. But this stucked it in this case with multiple dto representations. I'm not sure if create 3 generic types is a good way to handle this.

Another problem is that my controller layer is getting bigger with many mapping methods. Even using ModelMapper as automapper, some cases I prefer do it by myself than create complex converter classes.

How can I organize my dto mapping code and don't overload my controller with lots of mapping methods?

*P.S:* My project is a rest api with jax-rs, cdi and jpa

Comment: The question is a bit broad, but _one_ suggestion I have is to use MapStruct instead of ModelMapper; it is, in my experience, easier to manage and customize (as well as being much faster).

Comment: I'd also recomment MapStruct, the mappers get generated at compile time as opposed to runtime, and MapStruct mappers are injectible with CDI.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to follow the following rules:

- Separate the DTO that serve the API from the other domain classes, and use naming convention to quickly identify it (ex. XxxAPI). You may organize in a resource dedicated package : the controller, DTO and mapper classes.
- Don't be afraid to write a lot of code, especially in mapper classes, you may use some IDE tricks to generate and test them.
- Be careful using automapper, too much magic is dangerous, you may consider Builder patterns to facilitate your DTO / Domain mapping

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

A common approach is to split the DTO conversion logic into its own class. Depending on the size of the project, creating a repository class may also be useful. This leaves us with three classes:

1. **Controller**: Performs the REST operations
2. **Repository**: Obtains the DTOs from a database or Data Access Object (DAO)
3. **DTO Mapper**: Converts the DTO to a domain object

The repository allows us to hide the DTO from the controller entirely. Instead, the controller will only deal with domain objects and is made unaware that a conversion from a DTO to a domain object occurred at all.

The repository (let's say for `Foo` domain objects created from `FooDto` objects) is:

```
public Foo {

    private long id;
    private String name;

    // ...getters & setters...
}

public interface FooRepository {
    public List<Foo> findAll();
    public Optional<Foo> findById(long id);
    public Foo create(long id, String name);
    public Foo update(long id, String name);
    public void delete(long id);
}
```

The DTO conversion logic would be:

```
public class FooDto {

    private long id;
    private String name;

    // ...getters & setters...
}

public class FooDtoMapper {

    public Foo fromDto(FooDto dto) {

        Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.setId(dto.getId();
        foo.setName(dto.getName();

        return foo;
    }

    public FooDto toDto(Foo foo) {

        FooDto dto = new FooDto();
        dto.setId(foo.getId();
        dto.setName(foo.getName();

        return dto;
    }
}
```

With the `FooDtoMapper` created, we can create a `FooRepository` implementation:

```
public class DatabaseFooRepository implements FooRepository {

    @Inject
    private DatabaseConnection dbConnection;

    @Inject
    private FooDtoMapper mapper;

    @Override
    public List<Foo> findAll() {

        return dbConnection.getAllFromCollection("FOO", FooDto.class)
            .stream()
            .map(mapper::fromDto)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    // ...implement other methods
}
```

The `dbConnection` object is an abstraction of the database from which the DTOs are being pulled from. In this example, we can assume that `getAllFromCollection("FOO", FooDto.class)` returns a `List<FooDto>`, which we then stream and convert to a `List<Foo>` using the `FooDtoMapper` object (`mapper`). In your project, this will likely be replaced with JPA-specific code, but the principle still remains the same: Obtain DTOs from the JPA interfaces and convert them into domain objects using the `mapper` object.

This results in the following controller logic:

```
@Path("foo")
@Controller
public class FooController {

    @Inject
    private FooRepository repository;

    @GET
    public Response findAll() {
        List<Foo> foos = repository.findAll();
        Response.ok(foos);
    }

    // ...other controller methods...
}
```

Using this pattern, we abstract the logic for converting from DTOs into its own class and the controller is only responsible for dealing with domain objects.

In general, it is preferable to have many, simple classes that do one thing rather than putting all of the logic in a single class (like your original controller) in hopes of reducing the number of classes. For example, the `FooDtoMapper` is responsible for only converting from `FooDto` objects to `Foo` objects, and vice-versa. The `DatabaseFooRepository` is responsible only for getting DTOs from the database and using the `FooDtoMapper` to convert the DTOs to domain objects (i.e., getting domain objects from the database). And lastly, the `FooController` is only responsible for getting domain objects from the `FooRepository` (i.e., `DatabaseFooRepository` at run-time) and providing the necessary REST API metadata (i.e., HTTP status `OK`).

Note that in this case, the `Foo` and `FooDto` objects are identical and there isn't much of a reason to have separate `Foo` and `FooDto` objects (i.e., why not just store `Foo` objects in the database instead of `FooDto` objects?), but that is not always the case. Generally, the domain object and the DTO will vary. For example, the domain object may have a currency amount or date that must be converted to a `String` or other data structure that can be stored in the database (the DTO would have this `String` field while the domain object would have the actual field, such as a currency or date). In this case, I made the domain object and DTO the same for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: Your FooDto is a bean form because it has public variables AND getters / setters, instead of an actual DTO, which is a data structure with public variables but no functions. Right?